# Match all occurrences Regex Java

Tags: java, regex

i'd like to recognize all sequences of "word-number-word" of a string with Regex Java API.

For example, if i have "ABC-122-JDHFHG-456-MKJD", i'd like the output : [ABC-122-JDHFHG, JDHFHG-456-MKJD].

```
String test = "ABC-122-JDHFHG-456-MKJD";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+)-([A-Z]+))+")
            .matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The code above return only "ABC-122-JDHFHG".

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

The last `([A-Z]+)` matches and consumes `JDHFHG`, so the regex engine only "sees" `-456-MKJD` after the first match, and the pattern does not match this string remainder.

You want to get "whole word" overlapping matches.

Use

```
String test = "ABC-122-JDHFHG-456-MKJD";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=\\b([A-Z]+-[0-9]+-[A-Z]+)\\b)")
            .matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
} // => [ ABC-122-JDHFHG, JDHFHG-456-MKJD ]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/RwqR5s)

**Pattern details**

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead that matches a position that is immediately followed with

  - `\\b`  - a word boundary
  - `(` - start of a capturing group (to be able to grab the value you need)
  - `[A-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters
- `)` - end of the capturing group
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `)` - end of the lookahead construct.

Comment: It's a mistake to rely on word boundary. It will never match this "00`ABC-122-JDHFHG`"

Comment: A `-` is a non word char. `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` match *word* chars. A word boundary is an appropriate solution in this case.

Comment: I'm afraid not buddy, You're using the word boundary, in lieu of consuming anything, to advance to the next position which is `-` here `JDHFHG`, which is matched by `\b[A-Z]`. However, `\b[A-Z]` won't match "00`A`BC-122-JDHFHG" and won't match "_`A`BC-122-JDHFHG" where it should match `ABC-122-JDHFHG` ....... rendering word boundary totally useless. You're giving out bad advice ...

Comment: Word boundy's are not a panacea The real solution is not any boundary at all, and just consume `ABC-122-`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, overlap the last word.
***Make an array out of capture group 1.***

Basically, find 3 consume 2. This makes the *next* match position start
on the next possible known word.

`(?=(([A-Z]+-\d+-)[A-Z]+))\2`

https://regex101.com/r/Sl5FgT/1

Formatted

```
 (?=                           # Assert to find 
      (                             # (1 start), word,num,word
           (                             # (2 start), word,num
                [A-Z]+ 
                -
                \d+ 
                -
           )                             # (2 end)
           [A-Z]+ 
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
 \2                            # Consume word,num
```